# How to execute remote SSH command in background using PHP exec()?

Tags: php, bash, ssh

Is there a simple way to execute SSH commands in the background on remote machines from PHP without using `ssh2_*`? The PHP script is executed by the user from bash (no Apache involved), so it's not an issue of rights. I've tried doing this:

```
exec("ssh -f -o UnknownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i {$keyFile} {$user}@{$ip} {$remoteCommand} 2>&1 >/dev/null </dev/null");
```

For example:

```
exec("ssh -f -o UnknownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/data/id_rsa user@192.168.0.19 '/home/user/script.sh ; exit' 2>&1 >/dev/null </dev/null");
```

All PHP variables have been escaped with `escapeshellarg()` and `$remoteCommand` is a bash script on the remote machine that sleeps for a few minutes and then starts executing some commands.

My problem is that if I execute that SSH command from bash, it gives control back to bash immediately. If I execute it from php using `exec()` it waits until the remote command executes. I've tried adding `2>&1 >/dev/null </dev/null` after `/home/user/script.sh`, but the execution still doesn't return control to the PHP script.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with bash. Don't you want it to give control back to bash immediately? Aren't you trying to execute in the background?

Comment: If you don't mind elaborating, why don't you want to use ssh2_*?

Comment: @davidethell Yes, I do, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @favoretti I have used it before and it is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing an **&** at the end of your command for sending the execution to the background.

Comment: Yes, I was missing that, but it still didn't help.